# How to put scroll bar in vertical position and also how to move images with up and down arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulty to put the scroll bar in a vertical position instead of horizontal. Also, I want to slide images with up
 and down arrow key of the keyboard. Please help me I have an
 assignment due. I'll appreciate your help.
For more information please check my code into jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mgj7hb0k/

The code below is from HTML file

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slider" id="slider">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="slide" id="slide-0"><span class="temp">74°</span></div>
      <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><span class="temp">64°</span></div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide-2"><span class="temp">82°</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#slide-0" class="active">Slide 0</a> 
    <a href="#slide-1">Slide 1</a> 
    <a href="#slide-2">Slide 2</a> 
  </nav>
</div>

CSS file. I have added some styles into separate css file.The "slider" (visual container) and the slides need to have explicity the same size. We'll use pixels here but you could make it work with anything.

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100);

.slider-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.slider {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.holder {
  width: 300%;
}

.slide {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-position: -100px 0;
}

.temp {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#slide-0 {
  background-image: url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7347/8731666710_34d07e709e_z.jpg);
}

#slide-1 {
  background-image: url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7384/8730654121_05bca33388_z.jpg);
}

#slide-2 {
  background-image: url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7382/8732044638_9337082fc6_z.jpg);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, black);
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.slider-nav a {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider-nav a.active {
  background: #999;
}
```

We're going to use jQuery here because we love life. Our goal is the adjust the background-position of the slides as we scroll. We can set background-position in percentages in CSS, but that alone doesn't do the cool hide/reveal more effect we're looking for. Based the amount scrolled (which we can measure in JavaScript), we'll adjust the background-position. Alone, that would look something like this:

```
Js file  
var slider = {

      // Not sure if keeping element collections like this
      // together is useful or not.
      el: {
        slider: $("#slider"),
        allSlides: $(".slide"),
        sliderNav: $(".slider-nav"),
        allNavButtons: $(".slider-nav > a")
      },

      timing: 800,
      slideWidth: 300, // could measure this

      // In this simple example, might just move the
      // binding here to the init function
      init: function() {
        this.bindUIEvents();
      },

      bindUIEvents: function() {
        // You can either manually scroll...
        this.el.slider.on("scroll", function(event) {
          slider.moveSlidePosition(event);
        });
        // ... or click a thing
        this.el.sliderNav.on("click", "a", function(event) {
          slider.handleNavClick(event, this);
        });
        // What would be cool is if it had touch
        // events where you could swipe but it
        // also kinda snapped into place.
      },

      moveSlidePosition: function(event) {
        // Magic Numbers =(
        this.el.allSlides.css({
          "background-position": $(event.target).scrollLeft()/6-100+ "px 0"
        });  
      },

      handleNavClick: function(event, el) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var position = $(el).attr("href").split("-").pop();

        this.el.slider.animate({
          scrollLeft: position * this.slideWidth
        }, this.timing);

        this.changeActiveNav(el);
      },

      changeActiveNav: function(el) {
        this.el.allNavButtons.removeClass("active");
        $(el).addClass("active");
      }

    };

    slider.init();
```